# Does dartdoc have an equivalent to javadoc's @since tag?

Tags: dart

For **dartdoc**, is there an equivalent to javadoc's @since tag?  I'd like to mark some new methods as being available 'since version 1.1' which I can do inline...but I wondered if there is some standard handling for this in dartdoc that I missed.

Comment: Not yet, how about creating a feature request at http://www.dartbug.com/new ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature currently in dartdoc. There are no "@foo" tags at all in the dartdoc format.